# error from return mongoose mongodb document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am doing one of the freecodecamp backend certification api projects "url shortener". I have a basic express app, connected to mongodb by mongoose. I had set up one model. I am running all this on cloud9 (c9) developement environment. But as soon as i start the app, it throws this error and stops

```
 events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalUrl' of null
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/FCCBackendProjects/urlShortener/server.js:71:29
at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/FCCBackendProjects/urlShortener/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3755:16)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/FCCBackendProjects/urlShortener/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:277:21
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/FCCBackendProjects/urlShortener/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:408:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:337:13)
```

It says original url is undefined. but ofcourse it is defined. What could be the problem? need help please.

my files:

server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var urlPairModel = require("./models/urls");
var validator = require("validator");

var port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//connect to the database
var mlabUrl = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI; //get mlab url(credentials) from 
environment variables and url-shortner is dbname
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/urlShortener"); /*connect to 
mongodb(on mlab, no locally) with mongoose
either on mlab cloud remote database or locally installed mongodb*/

var connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'))
connection.on('open', function(){
console.log("connected correctly to the database");
    console.log( process.env.PORT);
})

app.get("/new/:id(*)", function(request, response){

    var originalUrl = request.params.id; //url user typed in

    //check if it's a valid url
    if(!validator.isURL(originalUrl)){
        response.send({error: "you can enter only valid urls"})
    }
    //create a shortened url representation
    var shortCode = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
    //create new urlpair from url model
    var urlInstance = new urlPairModel({
        originalUrl : originalUrl,
        shortenedUrl : shortCode
    });

    //save urlPair data instance in the database
    urlInstance.save(function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            response.send("Error saving to the database");
        }
        else{
            //return back to the user only the original url and shortened form
            console.log(data);
            var appUrl = 'https://bexis-url-shortener.herokuapp.com/';
            response.send({
            originalUrl : originalUrl,
            shortenedUrl : appUrl + shortCode
            });
         }
    })
});

app.get("/:id", function(request, response){
    //get users shortcode
    var shortCode = request.params.id;
    //find document with this shortcode in the database collection urlpairmodel
    urlPairModel.findOne({'shortenedUrl':shortCode}, function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            response.send("cannot find your shortUrl in database. Please add it" +
        " as new url /new/your_url_here");
        }
        else{
            console.log(docs);
            //check if docs original url does not have http in it
            var check = docs["originalUrl"].substring(0,4);
            //add http if it does not have
            if(check !== "http"){
                var urlToVisit = "http://" + docs.originalUrl;
                response.redirect(urlToVisit);
            }
            //it has http, so:
            //redirect user to appropriate url representation of the shortcode
            response.redirect(docs.originalUrl);
        }
    })
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("app is listening on port");
})
```

urls.js:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//create our url schema
var urlModelSchema = new Schema({
    originalUrl : {type: String},
    shortenedUrl : {type: String}
},
{
    timestamps : true
});


//create our url model --> mongoose will pluralize it
var urlModels = mongoose.model("urlModel", urlModelSchema);

module.exports = urlModels;
```

Comment: What does  `console.log` print out for docs on line number 70 ?

Comment: it prints this:
 `{ 
_id: 594d356a1eb7cc13b7691828,
  updatedAt: Fri Jun 23 2017 15:36:10 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  createdAt: Fri Jun 23 2017 15:36:10 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  originalUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
  shortenedUrl: '7529',
  __v: 0
 }`

Comment: can you print `console.log(docs.originalUrl)` and check if the error ocurs.

Comment: let's see... its prints this: 7529

Comment: that seems to be `shortenedUrl` value, not `originalUrl` as per your above log. Something is missing in your data or you are missing something.

Comment: It does not give this error when i view the app in the small cloud 9 window. But when i open the app in the browser on localhost ( localhost of c9 which is  "https://workspaceName-username.c9users.io/"), then it crashes and gives that error, even before we get to the line 70 console.log

Comment: i miss-wrote, it prints this:
`https://www.google.com`

Comment: Just do one thing, wrap your else code inside an if block. Like `if(docs) { your code } ` Then tell if its breaking.

Comment: SOLVED. It actually worked, such a strange thing. no more errors. Thank you. I thought the callback function naturally handled the "docs" part. I guess i have seen something useful today. Thanks @ Prabodh

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: was wondering how to "accept" your answer now, since its just a comment

Comment: I have added the resolution so no one would take much efforts further. If you find it helpful you can +1 as well :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this issue was checking if the docs are not empty before accessing the value

The Code

```
 app.get("/:id", function(request, response) {
  //get users shortcode
  var shortCode = request.params.id;
  //find document with this shortcode in the database collection urlpairmodel
  urlPairModel.findOne({
    'shortenedUrl': shortCode
  }, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      response.send("cannot find your shortUrl in database. Please add it" +
        " as new url /new/your_url_here");
    } else {
      // Soltuion part
      if (docs) { // Checking if docs are available before accessing
        //check if docs original url does not have http in it
        var check = docs["originalUrl"].substring(0, 4);
        //add http if it does not have
        if (check !== "http") {
          var urlToVisit = "http://" + docs.originalUrl;
          response.redirect(urlToVisit);
        }
        //it has http, so:
        //redirect user to appropriate url representation of the shortcode
        response.redirect(docs.originalUrl);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Great! was stuck on this for a while. I was thinking the nodejs asynchronous callback function, automactically passed back an error it there was one,  and then the docs, if there was docs.

**I guess you explicitly have to check if the docs are available still.** NOTED. Hopefully this helps someone else too. Anyway stackoverflow rocks. Thanks again @Prabodh

Comment: Its similar to mysql stuff, if you have no data. Its a blank response. Similarly if no data found, it will still come to success. As the query fired successfully only the matched data was not present there.